# How to concatenate new data from a separate file as a new column of a numpy array?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have 2 text files as follows: animals = ['tiger'; 'lion'] and birds = ['parrot'; 'eagle']

Now I have to fetch these values into a numpy array and the array must look as follows: 
[image]

So, I want to add the data from a new text file into the next available column. But I could only add it row-wise but not column-wise.

I have tried the following code:

```
a = np.array([])
for c in list:
    s = np.genfromtxt(os.getcwd()+c+'.txt', dtype = 'str', delimiter = ';')
    #s = np.reshape(s, (-1, 2))
    h = np.concatenate([h, s], axis = 1)
```

I am getting an error as follows: "AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1"

Tried many times using several techniques, but only getting the output as follows:
[image]

Can someone please help me out with this!

Comment: Why are you using numpy? If you have strings I think it's better just list of lists.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the logic below. I assume you have two lists animals, birds and your required array is list_req

```
animals = ['tiger', 'lion']
birds = ['parrot', 'eagle']
list_req = []
list_req.append(animals)
list_req.append(birds)
list_req = np.transpose(list_req)
```